# R 3.1.0 - Don't understand how this function works

Tags: r, function

i'm learning how to program in R (this is my second MOOC, first was Python). But i don't get how this function works. I've tried the forums but not answers yet. Please, some help.

**This is the function:**

```
f <- function(x) {
        g <- function(y) {
                y + z
        }
        z <- 4
        x + g(x)
}
```

What is the result after entering:

```
z <- 10
f(3)
```

**My questions are:**

1) The variable "z <- 4" It's a local variable? I say "local" because i used to writte code in python, and in this langague you have local and global variables. I don't know how it is in "R".

2) We don't have any value for "y". So "y" is ignored as a variable. But it is called as a "function": g <- function(y). Right?

3) How does the line: "x + g(x)" work?

I mean: a) first, the variable "g" is executed. So "y + z" is done... but with wich values? I see that "z" is after the function(y) is finished with the "}"... so "z <- 4" is taken as value for "z" in "y + z"??? Or not?

Please, help.

Comment: I'm not an R programmer, but it looks like it's declaring the function g inside f that takes the parameter y.  It then declares z = 4, then returns x + g(x).  If f(x) is called with x = 1 it would be 1 + 1 + 4 = 6.

Comment: Your result if z = 10 and passed in f(3) would be 3 + 3 + 10 = 16 :)

Comment: Please, answer in order to my questions so i don't get lost.

Comment: 1) Everytime you run `f()`, `z` is set to 4.
2) In your function, `y` is equal to `x`, as you call `g(x)`.
3) 1 + (1 + 4).

Comment: I assure you `f(3) = 10`

Comment: 1) Z is a local variable to f(x).  2) y has the value of x when g(x) is called, so if g(3) is called, y = 3.  3) The function g takes x as parameter and adds z to it.

Comment: @user3114046 The original poster asked for f(3) if z <- 10, not z <- 4 :)

Comment: Ah, I see now.  He was declaring z BEFOREHAND, not changing z <- 4 to z <- 10.  Yes, f(3) would equal 10 :)

Answer (score 3):

`z` is local to the function `f`. There's also a `z` declared in the global environment but it doesn't have an impact on the calculation of `f`, it's just there to try to throw you off; the assignment

```
z <- 10
```

(or any other value) before the call to `f` will not change the `f(3)`.

`y` is a formal parameter for `g` which will be evaluated when needed.

When you compute `f(3)`, you will calculate `3 + g(3)`. No `z` is defined in `g` so R will look in the next enclosing environment and find `z` is 4. Thus `f(3) = 3 + 3 + 4 = 10.`

Comment: So, the function "f" only cares of what is within it. It does not take in account "z <- 10".  interesant. 
How does it relate to the "enviroment"? Please, elaborate a bit.

Comment: @user3352567, remove `z <- 4` from your function. See what happens.

Comment: @Pascal. it returns 16.... so "f" looks for "z" outside as well, when it does not find it within "f"?

Comment: @user3352567, in the environment. Look what happens if you `rm(z)`.

Comment: @Pascal i see that rm(z) would remove this object from the enviroment. But which enviroment, since "z" is in the "g function" and in the "global enviroment"...

Comment: @user3352567, if you removed `z` from environment and let `z <- 4` in `f(x)`, `z` will always be equal to 4. If you remove `z <- 4` from `f(x)`, then you will get an error `Error in g(x) : object 'z' not found`. If you set `z` in your environment, let's say `z <- 10`, then no error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you are correct in saying that 'z' is a local variable...to a certain extent.  It is local in the sense that it does not exist outside of the declared function f, but on the other it's not local to the function g.  This is where R is a bit different from Python.  You don't need to explicitly bring global variables into a declared function, they are automatically accessible at all levels below it.  Now, because you define 'z' twice, once inside 'f' and once outside 'f', R will use the innermost 'z', in this case 4, when evaluating the function.
2. As pointed out in the comments, 'y' is just a parameter for the function 'g'.
3. In 'x + g(x)', it does exactly as the comments say.  First passes 'x' into the function 'g', wherein 'x + z' is computed.  In this case the order in which the function 'g' and the variable 'z' are declared doesn't matter, since the function 'g' is not called until the declaration of 'z', and as I said before once a variable exists it is accessible by all lower levels (i.e. the function 'g').  After 'x + z' is computed, that sum is added back to 'x'.  So we get, for 'f(3)', '3 + 3 + 4 = 10'.

Answer (score 1):

The pitfall here is to understand how R decides which environment to pick the value of `z` from. It will always look for the local environment, if `z` is assigned a value in the local environment it will pick that one. If `z` is not assigned a value in the local environment, R looks at the next enclosing, 'larger', less local environment. This process will be repeated until the global environment is reached.

Since `z` is called in `g`, R looks for the value of `z` in `g` and can't find it. R then looks in the less local environment of `f`, where `z` is defined before `g` is called so uses that value `z <- 4`. R never looks at the global assignment `z <- 10` in this case.